# How can I center a tooltip below an element that is narrower than the tooltip?

Tags: css

I have this code to center a tooltip below an element. It works fine for an element that is greater than or equal to the width of the tooltip:

HTML:

```
<div class="my_class">Some Stuff<div class="tooltip_botom">My Very Long Tooltip Contents</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.my_class {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tooltip_bottom {
  position: absolute
  bottom: -25px
  left: 0
  right: 0
  display: inline
  text-align: center
}
```

But what do I do if the content is narrower than the tooltip width? The CSS I listed above doesn't work in this case. How can I fix it?

Comment: What I want is for the tooltip to be centered underneath the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/mbsqvxho/) works for your situation. To center the tooltip, it uses left 50%, transform:translateX (-50%), with text-align center.

It uses white-space:nowrap to keep the text from wrapping, but this can be removed if the text needs to wrap and instead, a combination of min and max width can be used to control or adjust the tooltip box size.

CSS

```
.my_class {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:#ffffcc;
    padding:3px 9px;
    border:solid 1px #555555;
}
.tooltip_bottom {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    top:25px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.my_class:hover .tooltip_bottom {
    display:block;
    /* To wrap the tooltip text, use min-width/max-width to control tooltip length. Use white-space:normal to overwrite the white-space:nowrap from the wrapper.  
    min-width:145px; 
    white-space: normal; */
    background-color:#ccccff;
    padding:8px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="my_class">Tooltip Trigger Long
<div class="tooltip_bottom">My Very Long Tooltip Contents</div>
</div>

some text

<div class="my_class">Tooltip Trigger Short
<div class="tooltip_bottom">Short</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much! I'd never seen the ``transform:translateX`` thing before.

Comment: You're welcome:) The idea came from this helpful page - http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/